# Enable bbPress Forum to buddypress group only

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, bbpress

I am working on wordpress project, In this I need to enable bbpress Forum to buddypress group section only. And not other forum functionality out of the group.

Please guide me any hook or other solution which will help me to implement this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Activate retired BuddyPress Group Forums component (see Settings -> BuddyPress -> Component page in admin area). Then go to Settings -> BuddyPress -> Forum page and activate older group forum (on the right side). 
Do not install and activate external bbPress plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
But Here I can see any such option ???? Here is screen shot
http://prntscr.com/9slvcu

Comment: Settings -> BuddyPress -> Components -> Retired (1)

Comment: I did not understand, I can't find any option of forum inside
 
Settings -> BuddyPress -> Components

Comment: Enable component on this page:

`/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=bp-components&action=retired`